# C# Take combobox item from one form and add its name as text to another

Tags: c#, winforms

Ok so I'm attempting to create a simple game. In a nutshell it's a resource management game where the player will attempt to manage a thieves guild. In regards to running missions I've created a Thief class, a new instance of which is created when a new thief is recruited. I have coded within the thief class the ability to gain experience and level up.

Here's my specific problem:
I want the player to be able to select which thief/thieves to send on a mission. I have thought about it and figured that opening a new form and populating it with checkboxes is the easiest way to allow this. These checkboxes will be related to a `List<thief>` of thieves, the player then checks the thieves s/he wants to send and these are then stored in another `List<thief>` and passed on to the run mission function.

I've built a separate project with the intention of testing and playing around with this before putting it into the main program. The test project consists of two forms: The first (`frmMain`) with a textbox to hold the selected options and a button to open the second form (`frmSelect`).  Currently I can open and populate the second form (`frmSelect`) but when I try to add the checked options to the textbox I simply...well can't.

So far I have tried directly accessing the textbox by typing `frmMain.txtOptionsDisplay` in the cs file of `frmSelect` but it causes the following error:

> An object reference is required for the non-static field, method or
>   property

I tried to create a new form in `frmSelect` and make it equal to the active instance of `frmMain` with: `Form frmTemp = frmMain.ActiveForm;` and then alter the textbox using `frmTemp` as a go-between but that produced the error:

> 'System.Windows.Forms.Form' does not contain a definition for
>   'txtOptionsDisplay'.

Having searched both google and stackoverflow forums I've encountered answers that I either have never heard of (Threading) or answers that I kind've recognise but can't interpret the code pasted to make it relevant to my problem (delegates).

Any advice or pointers would be fantastic.

EDIT:
frmMain code:

```
    public frmMain()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        selections.Add("Option 1");
        selections.Add("Option 2");            
    }

    private void btnClick_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {            
        frmSelectOptions.Show();

        int length = selections.Count();
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {
            CheckBox box = new CheckBox();
            box.Text = selections[i];
            box.AutoSize = true;
            box.Location = new Point(50, 50*(i+1));
            frmSelectOptions.grpControls.Controls.Add(box);
        }
    }
    public void updateText(string option)
    {
        txtOptionsDisplay.Text += option;
    }
}
```

frmSelect code:

```
    public List<CheckBox> selectedOptions = new List<CheckBox>();

    Form frmTemp = frmMain.ActiveForm;

    public frmSelect()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnSelect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (CheckBox box in grpControls.Controls)
        {
            if (box.Checked == true)
                selectedOptions.Add(box);
        }

        this.Hide();
    }

}
```

I hope this formats correctly... I'm kinda new and don't know how to indent. Oh look there's a preview...

Does this help?

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow.your question is very hard to read, you should atleast post some code and explain your problem clearly.

Comment: So much text, so few lines of code

Comment: Also, are you using WPF? Winforms? Some other UI?

Comment: pass the values you want from frmMain to your frmSelect when you create frmSelect before you show it. Create public properties in your frmSelect and assign them before you do frmSelect.show(); read a tutorial on passing values between forms to improve your understanding. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171925.aspx

Comment: @judgeja while the comment makes sense I feel that if I knew how to pass values from frmMain to frmSelect I would know how to pass it back again. I will read that tutorial and look into it, will let you know if it helps. @ Tony Vitabile I'm using VS 2012 Windows Forms Application... does that answer the question?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that controls defined within a form by default receive the private access identifier. Hence you could just add a property along the lines of

```
public ControlType ProxyProperty {
  get {
   return txtOptionsDisplay;
  }
}
```

Besides from that you should think about wether what you're trying is actually a good solution. Manipulating forms from one to another will become a huge clusterfuck in terms of maintenance later on.

Comment: I'm beginning to realise that. I honestly can't think of a better solution: the end result is that a player will be able to select which thieves to send on a mission. Opening up a new window and populating it with checkboxes for him/her to select looks the best way to me.

Comment: this is off topic with regards to your actual question but you may also want to have a look into WPF/MVVM. In the long run it will make you write easier to maintain and understand programs.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using the [Singleton](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650316.aspx) pattern for your **frmMain**.  This will help safeguard you from accidentally launching another instance of frmMain and at the same time, will give you access to frmMain's objects.  From there, you can either write accessors to **Get** your txtOptionsDisplay or you can make it public.  Below is an example:

```
public class frmMain
{
    private static frmMain Instance = null;
    private static object LockObj = new object();

    public static frmMain GetMain()
    {
        // Thread-safe singleton
        lock(LockObj)
        {
            if(Instance == null)
                Instance = new frmMain();

            return Instance;
        }
    }

    public string GetOptionsDisplayText()
    {
        return txtOptionsDisplay.Text;
    }
}

public class frmSelect
{
    private void frmSelect_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Set whatever text you want to frmMain's txtOptionsDisplay text
        txtDisplay.Text = frmMain.GetMain().GetOptionsDisplayText();
    }
}
```

If you do go this route, don't forget to update **Program.cs** to use frmMain's singleton.

```
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        // Application.Run(new frmMain()); - Old method
        Application.Run(frmMain.GetMain());
    }
```

Comment: I appreciate the help but if you could clarify - What does program.cs refer to? I've touched on C# in Uni but we've only been taught to program from a form. Am I right in thinking program.cs would be used to call either or both forms? Or am I way off base here?

Comment: Think of Program.cs as an entity that governs what form gets loaded when you run your application.  When you first create a project and windows form, Program.cs will automatically be created and tasked with opening up a new instance of that form. You would need to tell Program.cs to call the Singleton method of your form, instead of simply calling "new".  If you are using Visual Studio, you should see Program.cs under the Solution Explorer.

Comment: Yeah I knew about program.cs sorry got confused with something my lecturer said. Saw the damn thing as soon as I loaded my project. Ok so I've followed what you said, looking at your code you're taking the text from a textbox on form one and displaying it in a textbox in form two. Am I reading that right? If so my problem is getting it to go the other way, from form two to form one. For some reason the same logic doesn't work, for example I can't type the code "frmMain.txtOptionsDisplay.Text = frmSelect.TxtDisplay.text" into frmSelect's code. Once again thank you for the help and the patience

Comment: Can you show me the code for your form 1 and 2 please?